# Application Insights - Not getting data for one IIS site

Tags: azure, iis, azure-application-insights

I have two load balanced Azure VM's hosting multiple IIS sites, same sites on both servers. Three sites use Application Insights and the Status Monitor shows all three as being connected with no issues.

Two of the sites are sending telemetry data normally but the third is not sending anything. It's the same situation on both servers for this one site.

I configured it yesterday and the strange thing is that this site was sending data briefly from one server only, and then that stopped. I never got data from the site on the other server.

**So my question: Is there any way to log Application Insights telemetry data errors?** I tried searching for solutions online but it's hard to find something relevant when googling about App Insights and error logging because the only results discuss implementing App Insights into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to diagnose issues with AI telemetry collection. They are discussed in detail in these blogs:

- [Diagnostic of ApplicationInsights SDK](http://sergeysharp.com/blog/2015/04/16/diagnostic-of-applicationinsights-sdk/)
- [Application Insights Self-diagnostics](http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/11/07/application-insights-self-diagnostic/)

Shortly, the essence is:

- One can use [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to collect AI traces locally with the following
  command: `PerfView.exe
  /onlyProviders=*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-Web,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Web,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Core,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-DependencyCollector,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-Rtia-SharedCore,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-WindowsServer,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-WindowsServer-TelemetryChannel
  collect`
- One can use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) with [Application Insights Diagnostics](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ApplicationInsights.Diagnostics/) package to get traces by executing the following query:
  `DiagnosticObservable.Create().Select(i => i.FormattedMessage)`
- One can use the same or another instrumentation key for AI to report self-telemetry (however, this won't work if any telemetry cannot be delivered from the box at all) by adding the following into the applicationinsights.config file: `<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule,Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"><DiagnosticsInstrumentationKey>DIAGNOSTICS_IKEY</DiagnosticsInstrumentationKey></Add>`

**Edit**: The trace namespaces might've been changed by now, one can find the latest version of the [AI SDK source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use PerfView to find the exception and stack trace being generated by the W3SVC ID I was troubleshooting. Very helpful!